# How to get Company Logo or Image

Tags: curated-data, wolfram-alpha-queries

I can see that companies have a logo in Wolfram|Alpha when I type in their name but I can't get them in Mathematica.

For example searching for *Apple, Inc.* in W|A one of the outputs is the Apple logo.  In Mathematica I looked to see what properties are available.

```
CompanyData["Apple, Inc.", "Properties"]
```

This gives "company logo" as a property with tooltip `EntityProperty["Company","Image"]`. I tried some ways to get the logo and they all fail.

```
CompanyData["Apple, Inc.", "Company Logo"]
CompanyData["Apple, Inc.", "Image"]
CompanyData[FinancialData["AAPL","Company"],"Company logo"]
CompanyData[FinancialData["AAPL","Company"],"Image"]
```

Does anyone know how to get the company logo?

Thanks,

Edmund

Comment: Enter any W|A query in Mma as WolframAlpha["your query"], then in the pod with the desired information: click on the Plus sign in the upper right corner of the pod and select "Subpod content". A refined query to get that information will be pasted into your Mma notebook.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
apple = Interpreter["Company"]["Apple"]["Image"]
```

[image]

```
Interpreter["Company"]["GE"]["Image"]
```

[image]

Also works for the continent and respects colours:

```
Interpreter["Company"]["Siemens"]["Image"]
```

[image]

**Update**

```
Interpreter["Company"]["Wolfram"]["Image"]
```

[image]

For Apple addicts:

```
ImageFilter[Max[Flatten[#]] - Min[Flatten[#]] &,
 ImagePad[Last@MapThread[ImageMultiply,
    {ColorSeparate[apple],
     {White, White, White, Darker@Green}}], 109, "Periodic"], 1]
```

[image]

Comment: (+1)  Very nice. :)

Comment: I like the structure of this answer most. Many thanks.

Comment: @Edmund - You are welcome. I learned myself something new :)

Comment: I upvoted your clock question. Why did you delete it? ("you're late" was a clock-pun)

Comment: @belisarius Not because of your nice comment, but because it was immediately downvoted. Bueno, creo que voy reactivarlo :)

Answer (score 16):

Another variation:

```
SemanticInterpretation["AAPL Logo"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This method is nice because you can do at once:

```
logos = SemanticInterpretation["AAPL, TSLA, GE and MSFT Logos"];
Column[logos, Frame -> All, FrameStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 10):

The problem seems to be that many companies, even some of the biggest, well known firms are not known in `Entity["Company","name"]` form to Mathematica. This holds for companies like Apple, Microsoft, General Electrics etc. I believe that `CompanyData` needs entities to be of this form.

If you want to discover a company's entity representation using W|A discovery you end up with `Entity["Financial", "tickersymbol"]`-like forms instead for those firms.

The set of things known of "Company" entities differs from those known of "Financial" entities:

```
EntityProperties["Financial"] // CanonicalName
```

> {"CIK", "Close", "Exchange", "HeadquartersCoordinates", 
>       "High", "Image", "Last", "LatestTrade", "Low", "Name", "Open", 
>       "OriginalSharePrice", "Symbol", "Volatility20Day", 
>       "Volatility250Day", "Volatility50Day", "Volume", "ZacksAnalystHold", 
>       "ZacksAnalystMean", "ZacksAnalystModerateBuy", 
>       "ZacksAnalystModerateSell", "ZacksAnalystStrongBuy", 
>       "ZacksAnalystStrongSell", "ZacksMemberCount"}

```
EntityProperties["Company"] // CanonicalName
```

> {"City", "Employees", "FoundingDate", "Image", "Industry", 
>       "Latitude", "Longitude", "Name", "Position", "Revenue", 
>       "RevenuePerEmployee", "TotalFunding"}

The list is clearly different, though there is some overlap. "Image" occurs in both lists and can be used to get Apple's logo:

```
Entity["Financial", "NASDAQ:AAPL"]["Image"]
```

[image]

and the logo of Wolfram Research, Inc, in `CompanyData` style:

```
CompanyData[Entity["Company", "WolframResearch::s9r9v"], "Image"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

or through `Entity` properties:

```
Entity["Company", "WolframResearch::s9r9v"]["Image"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

You can check with

```
Select[CompanyData[], StringMatchQ[#[[2]], ___ ~~ "appl" ~~ ___, IgnoreCase -> True] &]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

that `CompanyData` is really missing some big companies. Try replacing "appl" with "micros", or "IBM".

Comment: I am sorry - but I don't see your your point at all - see my update.

Comment: @eldo The point is that the OP is trying to get the logo through `CompanyData` (which, if you follow the documentation, seems to be possible), and I'm explaining why that doesn't succeed in the specific example he has chosen. I show that it works for other firms. Your update totally misses the point indeed.

Comment: I'm too tired now. Before I go to bed, please let me, in between, upvote your answer. Hopefully, I will comprehend your point tomorrow :)

Comment: Just a small point of information, IBM is in company data, to find it you need to be aware that it is referred to as "InternationalBusinessMachinesCorporation::vq88c". This seems to be one of the challenges of 'CompanyInformation'.

Answer (score 6):

Something like this?

```
WolframAlpha["apple logo", "PodImages", 
 IncludePods -> "Image:FinancialData"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: A variation of this: `WolframAlpha["Apple", {{"Image:FinancialData", 1}, "Content"}]`